# How to launch and later terminate cmd.exe in a console window with QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I need to run a visible cmd.exe window via QProcess, and eventually terminate it. The console window for the shell has to be in the foreground and must be visible to user.

If I start it using `QProcess::start()`, the console window never appears. If I start it using the class method `QProcess::startDetached()`, I can't use the instance method`terminate()` to terminate it.

Comment: I tried using QProcess start and startDetach
Problem with stratDetach is, it separates the process. I want to handle it in my application itself.

Comment: @AlexP Yes. I have a commandline utility. When I run it, it just run and close with in a second. but i want to show the tool to user at least via cmd.exe

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, `QProcess` has two modes of operation:

1. Normal mode when you use **instance methods** like `start()`. In this mode, the `QProcess` itself *is the console* for the running application, if it requests one. This console is a logical object (like a pseudo-tty on Unix) and has no visible appearance.
2. Detached mode when you use the **class method** `startDetached`. If the process being run requests a console, Windows provides a console window for it.

So, your only option to leverage a Windows-provided console window is the detached start.

If you wish a person to be left with an open console window after `cmd.exe` executes your commands, the following applies:

- Each of the commands passed for execution needs to be preceded by `/k`.
- The `/k` and the command are *separate arguments*.

To kill the process on application exit, you can use an instance of the following class, made a child of the application instance:

```
#include <windows.h>
...
class ProcessKiller : public QObject {
  qint64 m_pid;
public:
  ProcessKiller(qint64 pid, QObject * parent = 0) : 
    QObject(parent), m_pid(pid) {}
  ~ProcessKiller() {
    HANDLE hApp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION
                              | PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, m_pid);
    if (hApp == NULL) return;
    TerminateProcess(hApp, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hApp);
  }
}
```

Thus, to run `cmd.exe` starting with two `echo` commands, in a Windows-provided console window, and having it killed upon application exit, would be:

```
qint64 pid;
QProcess::startDetached("cmd.exe", QStringList()
  << "/k" << "echo foo"
  << "/k" << "echo bar",
  QDir::currentPath(), &pid);
new ProcessKiller(pid, qApp);
```

Comment: At least can we get the process ID of the detached process? Because I need to kill that process when I close my Qt application

Comment: Ok. The reason why I am using detached process is to user to communicate with cmd.exe
If I use start instead of startDetached, the cmd.exe just pops up and closes immediately.
There is a option to get the pid of the process in startDetached method but not sure how to close the cmd.exe using that pid

Comment: This the piece of code I am using to start an cmd.exe
[code]
    `qint64 pID;
    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "/k cd /d " << "c:\path to be opened";
    myProcess->startDetached("cmd.exe", arguments, "", &pID);'
</code>

Comment: Destructor code should be like this 

<pre><code>
ProcessKiller::~ProcessKiller() 
{ 
 HANDLE hApp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, m_pid); 
 if(hApp != NULL) 
 { 
  TerminateProcess(hApp, NULL); 
  CloseHandle(hApp); 
  hApp = NULL; 
 } 
}

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code will solve my issue:

```
qint64 pID;
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "/k cd /d " << "c:\path to be opened";
myProcess->startDetached("cmd.exe", arguments, "", &pID);

...
...

QString pidString;
pidString.setNum(pID);
QString killProcessUsingPid = "taskkill /PID ";
killProcessUsingPid.append(pidString);

system(killProcessUsingPid.toStdString().c_str());
```

Comment: I think It should be
path = "c:\path to be opened";
arguments << "/k "<<"program.exe"; 
myProcess->startDetached("cmd.exe", arguments, path, &pID);